H264 Streaming Issue with IDB
I am working on a WebRTC sender application using .NET Core, SIPSorcery, and idb video-stream to stream video from an iOS device. My signaling server uses WebSocket (Socket.IO). The peer connection is successfully established, and ICE candidates and SDP offers/answers are exchanged correctly. However, the video is not appearing correctly on the receiver side. The frames seem to be incomplete or corrupted despite continuous logs indicating that video frames are being sent from the sender side.
Tried sending the data by creating frames using buffer but the frame is partially rendered maybe due to the data which is being generated from idb video-stream is in form of chunks for single frame.
Environment:

WebRTC Library: SIPSorcery
Signaling Server: WebSocket (Socket.IO)
Video Stream Source:idb video-stream with H264 format
Platform: .NET Core 5

Steps Implemented:

Set up signaling server to exchange SDP offers/answers and ICE candidates.
Establish WebRTC peer connection using SIPSorcery.
Stream video from iOS device using idb video-stream --format h264.

Code Snippet:
Here is a simplified version of my current implementation:
Function to get iOS Stream
private static async Task<Stream> GetVideoStream()
    {
        string idbCmd = $"video-stream --udid {IOS_DEVICE_UDID} --format h264";

        ProcessStartInfo idbStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "idb",
            Arguments = idbCmd,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        var idbProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = idbStartInfo
        };

        idbProcess.Start();

        return idbProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
    }

Getting video stream and convert stream data to frames which are being sent to peerConnection
var videoStream = await GetVideoStream();
var rawFramesSource = new RawFramesSource(videoStream);

var h264Format = new VideoFormat(VideoCodecsEnum.H264, 96);
MediaStreamTrack videoTrack = new MediaStreamTrack(new List<VideoFormat> { h264Format }, MediaStreamStatusEnum.SendRecv);
pc.addTrack(videoTrack);

rawFramesSource.OnVideoSourceEncodedSample += (uint timestamp, VideoFormat format, byte[] sample) =>
{
    pc.SendVideo(timestamp, sample);
};

RawFramesSource class to convert stream data to frames
public class RawFramesSource
    {
        private readonly Stream _videoStream;
        public VideoFormat VideoFormat { get; set; }

        public delegate void EncodedSampleDelegate(uint timestamp, VideoFormat format, byte[] sample);
        public event EncodedSampleDelegate OnVideoSourceEncodedSample;

        public RawFramesSource(Stream videoStream)
        {
            _videoStream = videoStream;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            Task.Run(ReadFrames);
        }

        private async Task ReadFrames()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
            while (true)
            {
                int bytesRead = await _videoStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (bytesRead <= 0)
                    break;

                var sample = buffer.Take(bytesRead).ToArray();
                uint timestamp = (uint)DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds(); // Example timestamp
                OnVideoSourceEncodedSample?.Invoke(timestamp, VideoFormat, sample);
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _videoStream.Close();
        }
    }

Streaming screenshot at receiver side of incomplete frame

